# Can a named (bind) crash make a server unreachable?

Tags: linux, centos, bind, centos6

My server recently became unreachable, and after restart a named error was the last line I found in /var/log/messages before restart:

```
Jun 26 00:15:06 host named[1303]: error (network unreachable) resolving 'dlv.isc.org/DNSKEY/IN': 2001:500:71::29#53
Jun 26 06:38:55 host kernel: imklog 5.8.10, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
Jun 26 06:38:55 host rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.10" x-pid="1294" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
Jun 26 06:38:55 host kernel: Initializing cgroup subsys cpuset
```

Can a named crash make a server unreachable? I doubt it, as I assume I should still be able to login with ssh via IP, but the server did not respond...So, I am trying to make heavy guesses here.

Comment: I think you're looking at the effect, rather than the cause.

Comment: I agree with @TomO'Connor - your server lost network connectivity for some reason, which is why named couldn't resolve dlv.isc.org (and also why you couldn't SSH in).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BIND did not crash. BIND is complaining *because* the network is down, but it didn't take down the network. To find the cause of the network going down, you'll have to look elsewhere.